# catching exceptions from VisualStudio generated Asynchronous methods

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio

I have a WCF client generated by Visual Studio, and it generates the asynchronous methods for BeginX() and End(). If the service throws the exception, how/where do I catch the exception.

e.g.:

```
m_service.BeginMyServiceMethod(PriorDate, ServiceMethodCompletehandler, null);


private void ServiceMethodCompletehandler(IAsyncResult ar)
{
}
```

Comment: this might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050784/where-do-i-handle-asynchronous-exceptions

Comment: Someone posted the correct answer here, but then the deleted it.